# Make one element same position as another css

Tags: css

I've tried hard to find an answer but I can't so I need help.

If I have two elements (parent, child) with classes in html in different locations how do I make the child element translate to the parent location. ie how do I overlay two elements with the exact same position by using the location of the parent to set the childs location with css?

Comment: welocome to SO please add your code

Comment: please add code ,so that we can get a better understanding for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
#parent{
  padding: 0px;
  background: #00ff00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
#child{
  background: #000000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

A pure CSS answer for this question. Just set padding to `0px` and you have the top left corner of the child at the same spot as the parent's. Let me know if this isn't the answer you were looking for. Happy to help! :D